# Python SQLalchemy order_by 1.9 and 1.10 in correct order?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column `version_number` type `TEXT`.

Values look like this: `1.9` or `1.3` and now `1.10`

The problem is that if I do `.order_by(desc("version_number"))` the result is ordered like this:

```
1.9
1.3
1.10 # this is handled like 1.1
```

I need:

```
1.10
1.9
1.3
```

Currently I dont know what to do. I dont want to change the column type and dont even know whether it would help. I also want to keep a good perfomance, as I have 1k rows~ for eahc request, which must be ordered.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
.order_by(desc(func.string_to_array(BuildItems.version_number, '.'))
```

Does not work. `1.10` is still at the bottom

Comment: It can be done in postgres: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74283/how-to-order-by-typical-software-release-versions-like-x-y-z I think any solution will probably use a builtin function like `string_to_array` so you'll need to write your own query in sqlalchemy

Comment: @rdas Thanks for the link. Sadly I can't figure out how to use the solution correctly. I tried (see EDIT) but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `text` array to an `integer` array

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, cast 
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

.order_by(desc(cast(func.string_to_array(BuildItems.version_number, '.'), ARRAY(Integer))))
```